# Service reference instead of Web reference in a Metro App

Tags: wcf, soap, service, windows-8

I’m looking for a way to consume this web service from a NET 4.0 application:

http://resultsservice.lottery.ie/ResultsService.asmx

As usual, I add the service reference to the service and apparently the proxy is created and everything seems normal, however calling 'GetResults' method throws an exception:

```
var service = new LotteryResultsServiceSoapClient("LotteryResultsServiceSoap");
var results = service.GetResults(DrawType.EuroMillions, 1);
```

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

It’s rare, because other methods of the service (GetProjectedJackpot) are working fine. 
I’ve tried to add a web reference instead of a service reference, and surprisingly… it works fine. So, maybe I’m doing something wrong.

The issue is I cannot use a web reference because I’d like to port this application to WindowsRT, and metro applications don’t support web references.

Answer (score 1):

Web Reference generated proxies include a User-Agent value in the header of the outgoing HTTP message. Service Reference generated proxies do not add this value by default. Luckily, this behavior is pretty well documented.

It appears that the null object exception is resulting from the missing User-Agent value in the Service Reference proxy. The value being populated by the Web Reference is Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.269). Using Charles Proxy I was able to verify that adding this value to all out-going HTTP messages generated by the Service Reference will solve your problem.

WCF provides several possible ways to modify outgoing soap messages and HTTP requests. [Here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/paulomorgado/archive/2007/04/27/wcf-building-an-http-user-agent-message-inspector.aspx) is a really great article that discusses a couple of these solutions and contains some good code samples.

Comment: This solution (client message inspector) has been very useful for my NET 4.0 application, and now Works fine! However I'm unable to apply it to a metro application, because ther are some dependences of System.Configuration that is not allowed in WinRT...